# nginx invalid parameter cookie nginx,wordfence plugin

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to install wordfence on my wordpress website and it requested me to update my nginx.conf for caching, I created a new file name wp.conf and pointed included it in nginx.conf but when trying to restart nginx I get the following error:

```
    nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "cookie”" in /etc/nginx/wf.conf:8
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here is my wf.conf file:

```
    server {
 # WORDFENCE FALCON ENGINE CODE
    #Match on gzip first because ordering matters.
    location ~ “/site/wp-content/wfcache/.*gzip$” {
    gzip off;
    types {}
    default_type text/html;
    add_header Vary “Accept-Encoding, Cookie”;
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    #If the previous matched, the following location won’t be executed.
    location ~ /site/wp-content/wfcache/.* {
    add_header Vary “Accept-Encoding, Cookie”;
    }
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 1;

    #Don’t cache form submissions.
    if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }

    #Allow caching of /?123=123 because this is a common DDoS to override                 caches.
    if ($query_string !~ “^(?:d+=d+)?$”) {
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }

    #Only cache URL’s ending in /
    if ($request_uri !~ /$) {
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }
    #Don’t cache any cookies with this in their names e.g. users who are         logged in.
    if ($http_cookie ~* “(comment_author|wp-        postpass|wf_logout|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle|wpmp_switcher)”) {
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }
    set $wordfenceEncoding “”;
    #Oh, you want gzipped content?
    if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
    set $wordfenceEncoding _gzip;
    }
    set $wordfenceHTTPS “”;
    if ($scheme = ‘https’){
    #If you want to ENABLE HTTPS caching, comment out the next line.
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0; #Comment this line out to enable HTTPS caching.

    set $wordfenceHTTPS ‘_https’; #Uncomment this line to enable HTTPS         caching.
    }
    #The main purpose of this line is to capture the URL components into         variables.
    if ($request_uri !~ “^/*(?<wfone>[^/]*)/*(?<wftwo>[^/]*)/*(?<wfthree>        [^/]*)/*(?<wffour>[^/]*)/*(?<wffive>[^/]*)(?<wfsix>.*)$”){
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }
    #If the file doesn’t exist then don’t serve from cache.
    if (!-f “$document_root/site/wp-        content/wfcache/${http_host}_${wfone}/${wftwo}~${wfthree}~${wffour}~${wffive}~${wf        six}_wfcache${wordfenceHTTPS}.html${wordfenceEncoding}”) {
    set $wordfenceCacheOn 0;
    }

    if ($wordfenceCacheOn = 1) {
    rewrite .* “/site/wp-        content/wfcache/${http_host}_${wfone}/${wftwo}~${wfthree}~${wffour}~${wffive}~${wf        six}_wfcache${wordfenceHTTPS}.html${wordfenceEncoding}” last;
    }
    # END Wordfence Rules
    }
```

And this is the nginx.conf file:

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

       #gzip  on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid quotes in the `wf.conf` file.

In your `nginx.conf`, you have `"` as the quote character, and in `wf.conf`, you have `“`, which is not valid.

Change the quotes and the configuration should work.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct.